# Change the Auto-Indent Lines setting when using Flutter in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter, auto-indent

### Problem

Auto-Indent Lines improperly shifts indent of Redirecting constructors.

The result of Auto-Indent is below.

```
 Project.getInbox()
  　　: this.update(
  　　foo: 1,
  　　bar: 2,
  　　baz: 3);
```

The result I want is below.

```
 Project.getInbox()
     : this.update(
           foo: 1,
           bar: 2,
           baz: 3);
```

### Question

- How can I change the Auto-Indent Lines setting in Android Studio.

### Development Environment

- Android Studio 3.1.4

### Tried → Error

- Tried : I checked "Preferences" -> "Code Style" -> "Dart" -> "Tabs and Indents" and "Wrapping and Braces"
  →Error : There is no applicable place.

Best regards,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dart (and therefore Flutter) uses its own code formatter [dartfmt](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dart_style), so it's not possible to control indentation etc through the IDE. In this case, dartfmt will format the code differently depending on the optional trailing comma.

Without

```
  Project.getInbox() : this.update(foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3);
```

With

```
  Project.getInbox()
      : this.update(
          foo: 1,
          bar: 2,
          baz: 3,
        );
```

Comment: Just to clarify this behaviour, dartfmt doesn't support customization because it goes directly against code standardization. If dartfmt has only one type of code formatting, everyone's code will look the same, thus, allowing everyone to understand each others code easily.

You can learn more [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_style/wiki/Formatting-Rules).

Answer (score 0):

If you are an Android Developer and cannot leave Android Studio, since it's your coding home, but can't let go of flutter either.

**Use a different theme:
Visual Studio 2019 Dark Theme** (this auto adjusts indentation and makes code look exactly as of Visual Studio Code).
To install theme - plugins -> search "Visual Studio 2019 Dark Theme"

OR

**Use a different font:**
I prefer

Font : "Droid Sans Mono Slashed" or "Monospaced" (You can use any that works for spacing)

Font size: 18 , Line Height 1.4  // For 14 inch screens

Font size: 14 , Line Height 1.2  // For 15.6 inch screens or larger

[image]

OR

**A combination of above looks beautiful.**

[image]