# Android Studio wrong auto indent for dart

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter, code-formatting

I am a newbie to Flutter and I am happy to try this great technology. 
And I am going to try to follow this example https://medium.com/flutterpub/flutter-auth-with-google-f3c3aa0d0ccc to do a Google Sign in

Personally, I like to separate the chains of function call line by line instead of one line. It is like below:

```
  _googleSignIn
        .signInSilently()
        .whenComplete(() => {
        print("Login complete");
  });
```

However, when I do the auto format in Android Studio for these dart code, it give me the result in the picture below.

It give me not only an ugly code formatting, but also a wrong feeling of the scope of function.

Is there any way can help me to solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Add a comma after `}`

Answer (score 11):

I think yours is an issue of trailing comma.

`dartfmt` actually uses trailing commas to determine when to go to the next line, and yours is missing one at the end of your code. Try reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51907898/7280432) to understand why this is an issue.

Comment: You saved me a lot of pain. Thanks!